# $_POST not getting value from form post for select field

Tags: php, sql, forms

I have been stuck over this for almost a day now and I can not figure out whats the problem here. I need `$_POST['brand']` in the SQL statement here and I get a blank.

```
// sql for getting nearby stores
$sql = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(".$_POST['lat'].") ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS(".$_POST['lng'].") ) + SIN( RADIANS(".$_POST['lat'].") ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM stores
WHERE brand='".$_POST['brand']."'
HAVING distance <= ".$_POST['distance']."
ORDER BY distance";
```

This is the form in the PHP file.

```
<form method="post" action="./index.php" id="store_locator">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Store Locator</legend>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Address/Postcode: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="texta" name="address" id="address" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['address'])){ echo $_POST['address'];} ?>" />
            <span>e.g: "Sydney", "Magill Road"</span>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <label>Brand: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select name="brand" id="brand">
                <option selected="selected" value="bmw">BMW</option>
                <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
                <option value="ford">Ford</option> 
            </select>

            <label>Distance: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <select name="distance" id="distance">
                <?php
                // populate selected option
                $selected = 1;
                if(isset($_POST['distance'])) {
                        $selected = $_POST['distance'];
                }
                ?>
                <?php foreach($distances as $k=>$v): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $k; ?>" <?php if($selected == $k){ echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>><?php echo $v; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input buttons">
            <button type="submit" name="find" id="find">Find</button>
        </div>
        </br>
        <input type="button" value="Reset Map" onclick="reset2();" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

What am I missing here? Strangely `$_POST['distance']` is getting value. Please help. 
If I echo the SQL I see `brand =''` in the SQL statement.

This is the SQL code getting executed:

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(-31.9530044) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) - RADIANS(115.85746930000005) ) + SIN( RADIANS(-31.9530044) ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores WHERE brand='' HAVING distance <= 30 ORDER BY distance
```

**Contents of $_POST**

```
array(5) {
    ["ajax"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["action"]=> string(17) "get_nearby_stores"
    ["distance"]=> string(1) "5"
    ["lat"]=> string(11) "-31.9530044"
    ["lng"]=> string(18) "115.85746930000005"
}
```

Comment: Take the colon out after the selected attribute, what happens then?

Comment: You have a semicolon in the option tag, and what looks like a closing comment there after the ford option. Is anything commented out?

Comment: Ya, also, you're pretty vulnerable to sql injection.  Might want to sanitize your inputs by having a whitelist.

Comment: even after removing semicolon it does not work.

Comment: A way to test out mysql code is to `echo` the query (which will include all the variables), then run the echoed query in your phpMyAdmin (or whatever db software you're using). Then, you can check the output and make sure your query is formatted right.

Comment: print out the $_POST, is branding showing up empty, or not even in the array?

Comment: **your code is vulnerable .....bad guy will kill your db**

Comment: Mrxenotype is right, echo the query and execute the returned sql in your db client to see if you have sql syntax issues

Comment: I think we need to see more of your html

Comment: Can you post your entire form?

Comment: Executed the SQL - MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0005 sec ). So issues with syntax.

Comment: *WHY THE HELL IS YOUR CODE NOT FORMATTED?*

Comment: can you var_dump($_REQUEST) for me?

Comment: Wait so the sql didnt error just returned zero rows? That means your syntax is right, the critera did not find any database values, start removing criteria and figure out why a query you think will return rows isnt

Comment: @AJ. What is the SQL Code that you executed? Can we have that too?

Comment: @worthycaesar The problem is that 'brand' is not getting set in the SQL and I am not getting the expected results from the SQL. if brand='bmw' gets set I will get results. Thanks

Comment: @AJ. The rendered SQL. Without PHP. Please `echo` it out and update it.

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have updated please check at bottom of my question.

Comment: @akatakritos I have pasted the output of var_dump($_REQUEST) and I do not see 'brand' in the array. What does that mean?

Comment: @AJ. Can you also show us the `mysql_query()` part? If you are using Firebug / Chrome Developer Tools, can you check in the Network tab, if the `$_POST['brand']` is set or not?

Comment: @Phil I am. I have posted contents of $_POST. And I do not see brands here too. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: @PraveenKumar 'brand' is not getting set. Why could that be?

Comment: Remove the other options in the select input...does the query now contain brand?

Comment: Thanks all of you. Its was the hidden jquery function which needed to handle 'brand' as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That comment thread is getting too long.

> ["ajax"]=> string(1) "1"

You appear to be posting using ajax. We need to see the javascript you are connecting to the submit button.

You likely forgot to tell jQuery (or whatever function you are using) to serialze the `brand` select.

Comment: yeah if you are submiting using jquery you need to make sure to send the selected value and not the whole thing

Comment: @EyalAlsheich Your comment makes little sense. If using jQuery, one would simply use the [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function. Whatever the case is here, something else is intercepting the submit event and manipulating the data. +1